# Creating a unidirectional OneToMany relationship with Join table

Tags: playframework-2.0, one-to-many, ebean

I have a user table and interest table, the number of rows in interest table are finiate and i'm trying to model the senario that each user has a set of interests this is my code:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="user")
public class User extends Model{
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name="user_interest")
public List<Interest> interests;
} 


@Entity 
@Table(name="interest")
public class Interest extends Model{
@Id
public Long id;
public String   name;
public String   image;
}
```

naturally i would like to have joint table but the evolution is ignoring creating the join table and tries to do it by adding a extra column in the interest table. this is

```
create table interest (
19 id                        bigint auto_increment not null,
20 user_id                   bigint not null,
21 name                      varchar(255),
22 image                     varchar(255),
23 constraint pk_interest primary key (id))
.
```

what am i doing wrong?? how can i create a simple OneToMany relationship WITH join table in play2.2 using ebean?

thanks and regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's proper behaviour, `@OneToMany` relation in the `User` model can be read as `@ManyToOne` in the `Interest` model, which literally means 'each interest may belong to ONLY one user', so it's good enough if `Interest` contains field with the user's ID - `user_id` in this case.

Joining tables are used for storing MM relations, so to force usage of join table you need just to change the relation in the `User` model to `@ManyToMany`, so it will create you exactly what you want automatically. Of course if each interest can be joined with the only one user it doesn't make any sense as you'll need to control while saving if given interest isn't joined to someone else yet.

BTW: two tips:

1. you dont need to use `@Table(name="interest")` annotation if your model has the same name,  Ebean will create it automatically
2. If you are planning to move to postgress in the future (ie. on the Heroku) change the table name of User model to `users` (or something else) as `user` is a keyword in PG and it will cause conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing Ebean does not support @OneToMany with @JoinTable.

It is an open issue ([#123 on GitHub](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/issues/123)).